# Kick off mocha tests in Visual Studio Team Services Build

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I can't for the life of me find documentation or a tutorial for kicking off mocha unit tests in Visual Studio Online builds.

I have node.js app that is building in VSO and being deployed to Azure.  That all works wonderfully.  I can't seem to figure out how to kick off the spec files through the build process.

How is this done?  Is there documentation available somewhere that I'm missing.

Comment: It isn't mocha but here is an example with Karma so it should get you close https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2017/05/17/integrating-angular-4-unit-tests-with-visual-studio-team-services-vsts/

Answer (score 8):

Assume you have setup Mocha tests with your `package.json`, i.e. you run tests with `npm test`. For more information, refer to https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/test.

In your Visual Studio Online build/release:

- Add a "npm" task to install JUnit reporter

  - Run custom command `install mocha-junit-reporter`
- Add a "npm" task

  - Run custom command `test -- --reporter mocha-junit-reporter`
  - Tips: You may want to increase timeout by adding `--timeout 30000` because the build agent maybe running slower than your dev box
- Then, add a "Publish Test Results" task

  - Set "Test result format" to "JUnit"
  - Check the box on "Continue on error"
  - Under "Control Options" > "Run this task", set it to "Even if a previous task has failed, unless the build was canceled"

Queue a build, you should see Mocha test results in your VSO build.

> **BONUS!** You can also add code coverage to your Mocha run with [nyc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc) (formerly known as [Istanbul](https://istanbul.js.org/))

On top of the steps above:

- Install Istanbul locally to your `package.json`

  - Run `npm install nyc--save-dev`
- Modify your scripts in `package.json`

  - Update `{ "scripts": { "test": "nyc --repoter=cobertura mocha" } }`
- Modify the "npm test" task

  - Run custom command `test -- --reporter mocha-junit-reporter`
- Add a "Publish Code Coverage Results" task

  - Set "Code Coverage Tool" to "Cobertura"
  - Set "Summary File" to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/coverage/cobertura-coverage.xml`
  - Set "Report Directory" to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/coverage/`
  - Check the box on "Continue on error"
  - Under "Control Options" > "Run this task", set it to "Even if a previous task has failed, unless the build was canceled"
- Add a new build variable `NPM_CONFIG_COVERAGE` and set it to `true`

Now you got both unit tests and code coverage results in your build report.

Answer (score 0):

If you've configured you package.json to be able to run tests, adding a npm step that executes `npm run test` should do it. If you want to publish the test results you need to make sure that Mocha is writing its results to a format understood by Visual Studio Team Services. [JUnit format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-junit-reporter) would be a safe bet. Then follow up with a Publish test Results step that uploads the test results.

You can also use the Visual Studio Test Runner, combined with Chutzpah to run your tests, but I suppose that's going to be a lot of additional work to setup and isn't going to add much.

Comment: I think XUnit is the more supported format in VSO, see https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Test-Explorer#configuring-mocha-for-vs.

Comment: My bad. Tried on VSO and it said the XUnit test result XML is not in correct format. JUnit still the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of fiddling around i got it to work by adding a "Command line task" to my build definition, i used the following parameters:

- Set Tool to `node`
- Set Arguments to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\node_modules\jasmine-node\bin\jasmine-node --verbose test\`

My tests are under a "test" folder, also make sure you have jasmine-node as a dev dependency
[image]